# How to run a function to set height on all HTML tags of a particular type?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have some conditional renders of `textarea` elements in many places on a `form` that shows/hides these elements depending on what the user is doing. For example:

```
<li v-if="Form.Type === 1">
<textarea v-model="Form.Title" ref="RefTitle"></textarea>
</li>
```

There could be any number of `textarea` elements like above. What I need to do is resize these elements at certain points in the lifecycle (e.g. `onMounted`, `onUpdated`).

The function that gets triggered to do this is:

```
setup() {
...

const RefTitle = ref(); // This is the ref element in the template
    function autosizeTextarea() {
        RefTitle.value.style.height = "35px"; // Default if value is empty
        RefTitle.value.style.height = `${RefTitle.value.scrollHeight}px`;
    }

...
}
```

In the code above I am specifically targeting a known `textarea` by its `ref` value of `RefTitle`. I could test for its existence using an `if(RefTitle.value)` statement.

But how could I get all the `textarea` elements that may be rendered and then run `autosizeTextarea` on all of them?

I can get all the `textarea` elements like such:

```
setup() {
...

    function autosizeTextarea() {
        const AllTextareas = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA');
        for (let i=0; i < AllTextareas.length; i++) {
        // How can I set the style.height = `${RefTitle.value.scrollHeight}px`; 
        // in here for each element?
        }
        
    }

...
}
```

But how can `style.height` be set on all of them?

Comment: Ignoring Vue for a second: `AllTextareas[i].style.height` However you'll probably want to use a proper Vue mechanism for this; direct DOM manipulation is basically always wrong in a frontend framework. Here's how to do this properly: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1

Comment: I'd suggest you make a custom component with that functionality and implement it instead of a plain html textarea. You can even use v-model on custom components if you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own custom component representing a textarea with the functionality in the component itself, so you don't have to get all textareas which are dynamically created.

It could look something like this:

```
<template>
  <textarea :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" ref="textarea" :style="styleObject"></textarea>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  emits: {
    'update:modelValue': null,
  },
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
    },
    // Prop for dynamic styling
    defaultHeight: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 35,
      validator(val) {
        // Custom Validator to ensure that there are no crazy values
        return val > 10 && val < 100;
      }
  },
  computed: {
    styleObject() {
      return {
        height: this.$refs['textarea'].value.scrollHeight ? `${this.$refs['textarea'].value.scrollHeight}px` : `${this.defaultHeight}px`,
    }
  },
</script>
```

That way you can even use `v-model` on it.

```
<li v-if="Form.Type === 1">
<custom-textarea v-model="Form.Title" :defaultHeight="45"></textarea>
</li>
```

The Template I provided is just to show you how a custom component could look like. You might have to fit it into your logic depending on when you actually want things to change/trigger.

Comment: This is an okay suggestion. However, why still use refs? You could pass the textarea and set it's height like that. Now the answer is not downvote worthy but not upvote worthy as well.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I think you need the ref to get the `value` of the text inside it for the scrollheight?

Comment: I like the ternary operator for setting height. This solution is nice and reusable, but is having a component for individual form elements overkill unless they are very special complex elements? My `src/components` folder would become bloated with simple HTML elements

Comment: @volumeone That is completely up to you. I like having reusable custom components even for form inputs, that way I can keep my "masks" pretty clean and without specific logic to pick certain dynamically loaded elements. I personally don't mind having many minimal encapsulated reusable components. I like that approach more than having logic heavy "masks"

Comment: @D.Schaller The only problem is that across a web app there may be quite a few slightly different variations of the same element e.g. `textarea` is `35px` high in one form, but in another it may only be `20px` high etc. So I would have to have several `textarea` components as well or make the component accept these values as `props`. Which then does not make it more flexible than using the element directly in a component instead of via a child component.

Comment: @volumeone I use props to keep them dynamic. Whatever is changeable in the component is backed up by a defaulted prop. I'll update my answer to give you an example of what it would look like with that approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237468/discussion-between-volume-one-and-d-schaller).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it like this:

```
 const AllTextareas = ref(document.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA")); //returns an object not an array
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(AllTextareas.value)) {
        AllTextareas.value[key].style.height = AllTextareas.value[key].scrollHeight ? `${AllTextareas.value[key].scrollHeight}px` : "35px";
      }
```